# Failing to load byte[] or base64 data in Couchbase using C# client

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase, nancy, system.net.sockets

When trying to in/upsert a document using either `byte[]` or a `base64` encoded string I'm getting an exception and a `!result.Success`

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: count

My document doesn't contain anything named count.  This exception all carries an inner exception of

```cs
StackTrace

at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.SetBufferInternal(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   
at Couchbase.IO.Connection.Send(Byte[] buffer)   
at Couchbase.IO.Strategies.DefaultIOStrategy.Execute[T](IOperation`1 operation)  
...
```

This happens only when I include the field that has the `base64` or `byte[]` (re-factored to try both). On a windows7 pro 64 bit machine using NancyFX as the frontend and Couchbase as the database.

I have been unable to find any 2.0 .Net SDK or 3.0.2 Server documentation that would lead my in the right direction and have reached out to the **#couchbase** IRC with no luck yet.  There does seem to be any settings related to file size (the test data is a 26.7k png).  Hopefully its something simple that I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Note I've also tried converting to a json object prior to upserting with no luck.  Is this a .net couchbase driver level issue?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/delaneyj/cf169a7be1093628c4ee  here is a small example showing the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team encountered the same problem, we described it thus on the **#libcouchbase** IRC channel:

> Using the 2.0 .Net Client code, we are unable to inset a record of more
>   than 32K bytes, we receive the following error: "Specified argument was 
>   out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: count"

I got an immediate response:

> <jefe1> that is a bug fixed in 2.0.2 which will be released tomorrow [2/3/15]

We independently resolved the issue  by manually setting the buffer length:

```cs
cluster.Configuration.PoolConfiguration.MaxSize =
    ConfigurationSettings.Instance.CouchbaseMaxConnections;
cluster.Configuration.PoolConfiguration.BufferSize =
    ConfigurationSettings.Instance.CouchbaseBufferSizeBytes;
```

(I don't know the exact settings the team used.)

And, this is a link to the Couchbase checkin that describes and fixes the problem: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/commit/80ba3cfadc3aa8ba0dc889a16056252617628324

Comment: I used ```cluster.Configuration.PoolConfiguration.MaxSize = Environment.ProcessorCount;
                cluster.Configuration.PoolConfiguration.BufferSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 20;``` to test this (probably far from optimial) and it is working now.  Tried to log a bug but login/registration on couchbase doesn't seem to be working for me.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Just a head up about the release date, it's going to be later this week (and not 2/3/15)! Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Hi @jeffrymorris any idea when? I'm currently hitting the same issue and not feeling changing cluster settings like mentioned above. tnx!

Comment: @MichelTol should be up tonight or tomorrow - 2/10/2015

Comment: @jeffrymorris sweet! Tnx!